# How to reset python requests and avoid getting status code 500

Tags: python, http, session, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape links from a website using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and everything goes well until I reach around 510 requests, then I start getting status code 500 and then status code 414. If I stop the script and than starts again, it happens again.

I am trying to go over pages with car products and save links to all the cars. Since there are minor URL changes, I just increment the number of the page that I want links from.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
url = "http://www.olx.ba/pretraga?"
kategorija = "kategorija=18"
vrsta = "vrsta=samoprodaja"
sacijenom = "sacijenom=sacijenom"

stranica = 1
links = []
file = open('olx_links.txt', 'w')
s = requests.session()
while True:
    url = url + kategorija + "&" + "stranica=" + str(stranica) + "&" + vrsta + "&" + sacijenom
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
    r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
    page_content = r.content.decode()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, "html.parser")
    articles = soup.find_all(class_="naslov")
    for link in articles:
        links.append("%s\n" % link.a["href"])
        file.write("%s\n" % link.a["href"])
    stranica += 1
    if r.status_code != 200: #this part is ineffective
        s = requests.session()
        time.sleep(10)
    print(stranica, len(links), r.status_code, r.cookies)
file.close()
```

This is the part where I tried to solve the issue

```
if r.status_code != 200: #this part is ineffective
    s = requests.session()
    time.sleep(10)
```

If you want to try the code yourself you will need around 3-4 minutes to encounter the problem.

After exactly 508 requests it starts giving the following output:

```
507 14880 200 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
508 14910 200 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
509 14910 500 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
510 14910 500 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
511 14910 500 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
512 14910 500 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
513 14910 500 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
514 14910 500 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
515 14910 414 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
516 14910 414 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
517 14910 414 <RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

And then it just continues with 414

Comment: what is the error message when you got 500 error?

Comment: @Enix According to w3.org it is "The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request." If there is another way to go into details of error message through this package, I would like you to tell me

Comment: forgive me, but wouldn't it be `requests.Session` instead of `requests.session`?

Comment: have u tried to run the script from `stranica=510`. do you get the same error?

Comment: @SRC That is also a weird difference, that I don't understand. I tried both, none worked. The first I tried was requests.Session, but later I found the only [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313084/how-to-completly-reset-requests) that asks similar question and they used requests.session

Comment: @Enix Yes, I tried. I can accomplish the task that I want, but I need to manually change the value of `stranica`, I am wondering if there is a way to go from start to end, without interfering with the code.

Comment: @Enix @SRC I am sorry for bothering, but this is solved @SRC was right, I just need to use `request.Session` instead of `request.session`

Comment: Great to know that :)

Comment: @SRC Oh snap, It doesn't work. I thought it worked, because it had few 500 status codes and came back with status code 200, but after 508 requests, it receives 6 500's and then continue on with status code 414. It happens always the same. You can even reproduce the exactly same problem.

Comment: Again a wrong `While True` usage ! Under while true: **All procees required in a single loop!**  Like this : we got 3 process , our tree is > `def func1(): ... end_line_call_ func2() ; def func2():end_line_call_ func3(); def func3(): return_value+compare_status+recall_any_function,return_some_status_flag;while True: func1()` you can't live if you are def !

Comment: @dsgdfg Could you explain your point?

Comment: where your process chain ? i see on your example `for` iterators  work parallel with other tasks.

Comment: @dsgdfg I appreciate your will to help, but I don't get you!

Comment: `r.status_code != 200` mean non string and zero length  itams can acceptable.... 200 is first header part for declare `server is alive`, your requested server is alive but give you nothing ! @mrGreenBrown And mu other warnings is "for good coding and handle all errors"